# Trying to access array offset on value of type bool - Laravel API json response

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting an error in Laravel when trying to populate a response from an API.
ErrorException
Trying to access array offset on value of type bool (View: C:\laragon\www\testapi\resources\views\order.blade.php)

Sample API response.

```
{
"success": true,
"desc": "success",
"details": [{
"awb_no": "",
"orderid": "BIG000013",
"status": "Error",
"reason": "S10",
"data": null
}]
}
```

This is the code from the controller.

```
 $response = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
 $response_obj = json_decode($response, TRUE);

 //return $response_obj;
 return view('order', ['data' => $response_obj]);
```

This is the code from 'order' view

```
@foreach($data as $item)
{{ $item['desc'] }}
@endforeach
```

When I google the error, most of the answer is pointing towards using lower php version and do a composer update. Which I've done both. Still getting the same error. Anything wrong with the code? Got the code from sample tutorial in youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$data` is not an array, it's a single object and you're using `foreach` on an object which is causing the error.

**You can directly access the `desc` value as:**

```
{{ $data['desc'] }} // success
```

Also, `details` is an array, whose value can be accessed as:

```
@foreach ($data['details'] as $item)
    {{ $item['orderid'] }} // BIG000013
    {{ $item['status'] }} // Error
@endforeach
```